# Why is SWI-Prolog only giving one solution?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, logical-purity

I'll be honest, I'm a Prolog newbie, so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a simple predicate to count the occurences of an atom in a list, as follows:

```
count(L, B, C) :-
    L = [], C = 0, !;
    L = [H|T], H \= B, count(T, B, C), !;
    L = [H|T], H = B, count(T, B, C1), C is C1 + 1.
```

The following queries return the correct results:

```
?- count([a, c, g, t], a, C).
C = 1.

?- count([a, c, g, t], c, C).
C = 1.

?- count([a, c, g, t], g, C).
C = 1.

?- count([a, c, g, t], t, C).
C = 1.
```

However, if I try to find all possible solutions, it only gives one.

```
?- count([a, c, g, t], X, C).
X = a,
C = 1.
```

How do I get it to give all the solutions? I though it could have something to do with the cut operator, but removing it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why don't you write it as multiple predicates?

Comment: I could have. It was just a stylistic choice I guess.

Comment: +1 for learning by implementing common list functions

Comment: @Arian actually I just needed it for something - I don't think there's anything like `count/3` built into SWI Prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cuts are indeed one problem: Try for example the most general query

```
?- count(Ls, L, C).
```

and see that it yields only a single solution, although there clearly should be infinitely many because the first argument can be a list of arbitrary length. So first remove all cuts. The other problem is `(\=)/2`, which is not a true relation: It is only sound if its arguments are ground. Instead of `(\=)/2`, use the more general predicate `dif/2`, which is available in SWI-Prolog as well as other systems and constrains its arguments to be different terms. Your predicate will then work in all directions.

**EDIT**: I expand on the "usable in all directions" point. Consider the following version of `list_term_count/3`, which relates a list to the number of occurrences of a term in that list, using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints in addition to `dif/2`:

```
list_term_count([], _, 0).
list_term_count([L|Ls], L, N) :-
        list_term_count(Ls, L, N0),
        N #= N0 + 1.
list_term_count([L|Ls], E, N) :-
        dif(L, E),
        list_term_count(Ls, E, N).
```

We can use it in the most general way imaginable, which is leaving all arguments unspecified, and obtain correct answers:

```
?- list_term_count(Ls, E, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
N = 1 .
```

To fairly enumerate all solutions, we can use `length/2`:

```
?- length(Ls, _), list_term_count(Ls, E, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_G167],
N = 0,
dif(_G167, E) .
```

Notice the `dif/2` constraint which occurs as a residual goal, and which constrains the list's element to be distinct from `E` when `N` is `0`. This is how we can express an infinite set of terms that is not restricted in any other way except for being different from `E`.

Any other instantiation pattern is also admissible. For example:

```
?- list_term_count([a], E, N).
E = a,
N = 1 ;
N = 0,
dif(E, a).
```

Or for example:

```
?- list_term_count([X], a, N).
X = a,
N = 1 ;
N = 0,
dif(X, a).
```

This generality is one of the benefits of using pure monotonic predicates in your programs. Using pure goals also allows us to quite freely reorder them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're exploring the «dark side» of Prolog: aggregation.

Indeed, your count/3 predicate could be - courtesy of library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) -

```
count(L, B, C) :-
    aggregate(count, member(B, L), C).
```

Being a language based on a `relational` data model, we are akin to expect the usual goodies available from SQL, starting from the simpler ones:

```
select count( distinct B ) from L
```

If you inspect the library implementation, (for instance by means of `?- edit(aggregate/3).`), you will appreciate the complexity required to generalize the 'one tuple at time' oriented Prolog *execution* model to a 'set oriented' one.

Comment: This is way less general than the solution that OP can easily obtain by using pure predicates (`dif/2`) in the given code sample. Try for example `?- count(Ls, L, C)` with your version (it doesn't work), or `?- count([X], a, C)`, which yields only one solution although there should be two, or `?- count([a,b,c], x, C)`, which yields `false` instead of `C=0`.

Comment: Dark side? Well, many forms of aggregation are not monotonic.

Comment: @false: performing aggregation in Prolog is rather difficult, specially if (superficially) compared to SQL. At least, that was my experience.

Comment: The primary difficulty stems from it being not monotonic. A comparison to SQL is hairy: you would need a lot of handwaving to formulate a monotonic subset of SQL..

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected behavior comes from Prolog's Unification, which always tries to succeed.

Read  `H \= B` as `not(H = B)`. When `B` is unbound, `H = B` will always succeed, because unification is possible, thus `not(...)` will always fail. As a result, recursion will only occur in the third branch, after `B` was bound to `H`.

Let's imagine `H \= B` would succeed for an unbound `B`, and the recursion happens. Now, if the same element `H` occurs again, it may be bound to `B` this time, which will give you multiple results for each value. E.g., `count([a,a],X,C)` would return `X = a, C = 1. X = a, C = 2.`. Certainly not what you wanted.

> However, if I try to find all possible solutions, it only gives one.
>
> ```
> ?- count([a, c, g, t], X, C). X = a, C = 1.
> ```

What would you say are "all possible solutions"? The are infinite values for `X` for which `C` is zero (Protip: try `?- X.`). Or do you mean all values in the list?

There is a very simple solution to your problem: just make sure `B` is bound when `\=` is reached. The easiest way to achieve this is simply changing the order of predicates, i.e., move the inequality to the end.

```
% count(?List, ?Element, ?Count)
count([], _, 0).
count([E|R], E, C) :-
     count(R, E, C0),
     C is C0+1.
count([F|R], E, C) :-
     count(R, E, C),
     F \= E.
```

Optimizations are left as an exercise to the reader.

A final note: don't use cuts (`!`) until you actually understand them, most of the times you won't need them anyway.

Comment: +1 for good explanation of why `\=/2` and `dif/2` are (ba dum bum) different. It's difficult to Google those predicates.

Comment: It was a toss up between this and mat's answer. I wish I could accept them both.

Comment: That's fine. mat's explanation goes into much more detail. But upvotes are appreciated ;-)

Comment: This particular implementation of `count/3` is *very* inefficient!

Answer (score 0):

Well this seemed to work.

```
base(a).
base(c).
base(g).
base(t).

count(L, B, C) :-
    base(B),
    (
        L = [], C = 0;
        L = [H|T], H = B, count(T, B, C1), C is C1 + 1;
        L = [H|T], H \= B, count(T, B, C)
    ).
```

That makes sense, since Prolog doesn't have any other way to know what the domain of B is I suppose. I'm just surprised it didn't give me that 'argument not sufficient instantiated' error the original way. Also, if I include the cut operators it doesn't work, which I'm also unable to account for as of yet.

Comment: This is way less general than it could be: For example, `?- count([a,c,g], x, C)` yields `false` instead of `C=0`. Use the `dif/2` constraint to restrict the domain of `B` while still allowing any other Prolog term. And do not use any `!/0`, they make this program less general: In this case, this is because adding `!/0` to the last few lines also cuts away solutions of the `base(B)` goal, which is not at all what you intended. Strive for generality, your relations should be usable in many directions. The name `count/3` does not suggest that, what about naming it `list_element_count/3` instead.